# 70s TV rendering of some old sci-fi story (aliens in the sky doing experiments with bodies - blood and body parts fall on Earth)

Tags: story-identification, tv

Okay, this is going to be a tough one.
Back in the seventies (max early eighties) I watched a TV production - a low cost one with basic (not so special) effects - probably only painted backgrounds. It looked like a British production (for the style).

What I remember of the story: strange happenings all over the world; people and cattle disappear, body parts are found as if fallen from the sky; possibly a blood rain over some cities. 
Special effects were almost nonexistent - mostly backdrops. It could have been a radio show adaptation of a H.G. Wells short story, transposed for television. If I remember correctly it was set at the end of the XIX century or, at most, the beginning of the XX century.

I remember that in the end the mystery is solved:

It was aliens that were experimenting with the lifeforms of this planet. The aliens were small spiderlike creatures, transparent and lighter than the air. They died for some reason I cannot remember (somehow like in The War of the Worlds). At the end, one of the protagonists has a dead alien specimen in a jar, paints it in some color and let it float upwards to show how they were lighter than air.

This was not a movie, it was at most half an hour, forty minutes long, possibly part of a series of two or three similar productions. Probably shot in a single studio, with backgrounds.

I had seen it on a Christmas eve of particular significance to me, and it would be nice to find it to try to recover part of that lost atmosphere. Monsieur Proust willing.

Comment: If not for the happy ending (from the human point of view), I'd think this might be a loose adaptation of Robert A. Heinlein's "Goldfish Bowl." Although that one wasn't set back around the year 1900 . . .